# button stopPropagation not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a button:

```
<button id="btnSearch" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSearch_Click">Find</button>
```

And code on back side:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSearch.InnerText = "Clicked!";
}
```

That I am trying to stop from executing. So I built a jQuery function like this:

```
    $("[id$=btnSearch]").on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).html("Searching...");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

But the code still reaches the back side.  I want to create a condition that if reached, my button will not go to the code behind, but I seem to have trouble just stopping it in the first place.  Normally e.preventDefault() works. Why is it not working in this case? For the record, both the jQuery and back side functions are successfully being reached.

Comment: I think your selector may be wrong. Why not just use '$("#btnSearch")' ?

Comment: does it help if you change the button type?  specify type=button, browser maybe using submit?

Comment: @RandomWebGuy - its a ASP.NET control so that id will be changed once rendered.

Comment: What's the ID when it's rendered? Can you use `ClientIdMode="static"` to preserve the ID? If not, maybe consider assigning it a class and using that as the selector.

Comment: Tried using ClientIdMode="static" and changed the jquery capture to #btnSearch but nothing has changed. Both jQuery and back side are being reached and executed.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: I am using chrome.  There are some unrelated errors yes.  If i use <asp:button ...> everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your jquery is not getting the id of that button. Try this..

```
<button id="btnSearch" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSearch_Click" ClientIdMode="static">Find</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#btnSearch").on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).html("Searching...");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

**EDITED**

Just remove onserverclick from your button. Like this

```
<button id="btnSearch" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static">Find</button>
```

And fire that event from your jquery code. like this

```
$("#btnSearch").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).html("Searching...");
    if (condition) {
        //IF TRUE    
        var SearchButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>");
        SearchButton.click();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work.  It says "searching" and then "clicked", so the propagation is not prevented.

Comment: do you want to post back your page?

Comment: no I just want to control the postback.  If a condition is met, go on with the postback, otherwise don't do a postback.  If I used an <asp:button ...> this would be simple, but using <button ...> with a runat="server" is causing some unexpected and unprecedented issues.

Comment: There are ways around this obviously, I was more concerned as to why the expected method is failing.  Nonetheless you did answer the question at hand, although I am still left puzzled, so I'm giving you the check, and seeing your score, a +1 to help you boost your score a bit :)  Thanks Sen.  Man this is a weird one.

Comment: Yes Indeed. some times things work perfectly and some times not. But we all are here to help each others. No problem Man

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate option covering other submit possibilities (as enter key) is using a `submit` handler

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    if (condition) {
        return false; // cancel submit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're using `onserverclick`.

The [HtmlButton.OnServerClick docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick(v=vs.110).aspx) state the following:

> The ServerClick event is raised when the HtmlButton control is
>   clicked. This event causes a round trip to occur from the client to
>   the server and back. It is deliberately different from the client-side
>   OnClick event. **If a conflict exists between code run with a
>   ServerClick event and code run by a client-side OnClick event, the
>   server-side event instructions will override the client-side code.**

Its likely that this is overriding and preventing your client `onclick` from being seen executing as you expect.

> I want to create a condition that if reached, my button will not go to the code
>   behind

In order to optionally call the code behind, you will likely need to remove the `onserverclick` and manually call `__doPostBack` in your `onclick` when the condition is met.

Comment: Thank you so much Cweston, this is exactly what I was looking for and when I fire up debugging tools, I noticed that the onserverclick got replaced by onclick=doPostBack("...","")  How interesting...  I gave you a +1 for the explanation and I really hope you get a lot more up-votes for shining some light to this mystery.  Thank you again!